# Scala Queue import error

Tags: scala

If I import `scala.collection._` and create a queue:

```
import scala.collection._
var queue = new Queue[Component]();
```

I get the following error:

```
error: not found: type Queue
```

However, if I also add

```
 import scala.collection.mutable.Queue
```

The error will disappear.

Why is this happening?
Shouldn't `scala.collection._` contain `scala.collection.mutable.Queue`?

Comment: Mutable collections are not included by default.

Answer (score 2):

You have to know how the Scala collections library is structured. It splits collections based on whether they are mutable or immutable.

`Queue` lives in the `scala.collection.mutable` package and `scala.collection.immutable` package. You have to specify which one you want e.g.

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable._
import scala.collection.mutable._

scala> var q = new Queue[Int]()
q: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int] = Queue()


scala> import scala.collection.immutable._
import scala.collection.immutable._

scala> var q = Queue[Int]()
q: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue()
```

Answer (score 0):

After `import scala.collection._` you can use `mutable.Queue`; you could write `Queue` if there was a `scala.collection.Queue` (or one of `scala.Queue`, `java.lang.Queue`, and `scala.Predef.Queue`, since all of their members are imported by default), but there isn't.

It should be easy to see why it works this way: otherwise, the compiler (or anyone reading your code) would have no idea where they should look for the type: do you want `scala.collection.Queue`, `scala.collection.mutable.Queue`, or `scala.collection.some.subpackage.from.a.library.Queue`?