# Queue not recognized

Tags: scala

I want to use an immutable Queue in Scala, like this:

```
var a:Queue[Int] = Queue.empty[Int]
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error: not found: type Queue
```

I tried importing the library containing it but there was no effect:

```
import scala.collection.immutable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala Queue import error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383143/scala-queue-import-error)

Comment: I've marked this as duplicate since you asked the same question before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you need to add `._` to your import, like so:

```
import scala.collection.immutable._
```

Or import Queue specifically as:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Queue
```